# Does AOSP or Graphene OS support COPE mode for enterprise device enrolment from setup wizard

Tags: android, mdm, device-policy-manager, device-owner, android-enterprise

I am looking for a solution to customize the setup wizard app in Graphene OS to ask for QRCode based device enrollment in COPE mode

The idea is to complete the organization managed device profile setup from the setup wizard using the testDPC app.